# How to distinguish always null object from null at first objects?

Tags: android, null

On my android app, I need to read some information from TelephonyManager right after boot is completed.

On the first try it always returns null, so I keep calling the method until it returns the value (usually takes 3-4 tries).

There are some rare devices that will always return null as they don’t have this value I’m looking for, so the app is stuck on a loop and crashes eventually.

How can I avoid that? I thought counting the times it tries getting the value and limit it with a number, so if it is still getting null I would just disable the app, but that seems a bit unstable.

My code is something like:

```
private void main () {
    //...code...
    while (getDeviceVersion()==null)
    {
        Log.d("Error","Cannot read the data yet");
    }

    //continue with code cause the data was received

}

private String getDeviceVersion ()
{

      TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
      String version = telephony.getDeviceSoftwareVersion();

      return version;         
}
```

Any other ideas? I would appreciate any kind of help… Thanks!

Comment: explain `but that seems a bit unstable`?

Comment: you can maintain a count that how many times it try to read the data and get null you can stop calling after a specific count like if you set the maxcount = 30 then you will stop calling method after 30 try

Comment: What is the information you're trying to read ?

Comment: By ‘unstable’ I meant that I don’t want to set a counter to a number without knowing what that number should be. I’ve tried my code on several devices and some returned the value after 2-3 tries and other after 7-8. I can set the counter to 30 to be sure but I thought maybe there is a better way to handle it.


I’ve edited the question to show an example of my code.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd say you should probably wait a bit between two call to `getDeviceSoftwareVersion`, so that the TelephonyManager has some time to actually read it. You can use a `Timer` and a `TimerTask` for that.

I don't see anything that could tell you if this info is going to stay null forever of if it's going to change, so I think you can only count the number of attempts and stop trying after a predefined number ( if you want 1 sec between each call, 10 attempts should be enough). Of cource you'll need a waiting UI for the user.

A warning also : calling this method might crash some wifi-only device (see [this documentation](http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Android-Programming-Guide-Compatibility-Issues) from samsung). It would be better if you could substitute if with information from [android.od.build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html).